# How to protect cd data with a signup form

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, forms, password-protection

This is probably a ridiculous question to which you will say you cannot, however...

I need to burn some files to CD / DVD for distribution.
I need people who open the CD / DVD to have to fill in a form that would send information to a web server before allowing access to the files.

I don't think there is a way of doing this, however other people know a way to do it...

Comment: Will every user be accessing the same disc or they will be issued a disc after they sign up in the web portal?

Comment: Well this might sound daft but the plan was to give the cd to a person, one cd per person and capture their user data after they have received the disk, from the disk itself. My friend was asking me about this and wondered if something like autorun script could do the job. I don't think so to be honest.

Comment: If it is an application you have developed that you are going to distribute, then it makes sense to add some kind of activation mechanism (which would also serve the purpose of collecting user information) rather than password protecting the files!

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to protect files would be to use a password protected 7zip file.
Depending on the number of discs you need to distribute, you could burn the zipped files in a few groups, which each one of them would use a different password.

The form should be used to register yourself and get access to the password, providing the ID of the disc.